# Почему нету ответа от сервера redis

Tags: php, linux, ооп, redis, memcache

создал файл

---

**request.php**

```php
<?php

$memcache = new Memcache();
$memcache->addServer('localhost',11211);

$value = $memcache->get('test');

var_dump($value);
```

прописал в консое **linux**

> **php request.php**

получил в консоль *response*

> bool(false)

а ожидал получить 
"hello !!!!" как в консоле **redis**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что я делаю не так и как получить *response* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> что я делаю не так

Пытаетесь подключиться к Memcache, думая что он Redis. Подключайтесь с помощью php-redis или https://packagist.org/packages/predis/predis

Будет что типа

```
$redis = new Redis(); 
$redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379); 
echo "Server is running: ".$redis->ping();
```